# FullCalendar Vue: viewType "timeGridWeek" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I'm trying to use the [timeGridWeek](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timegrid-view) view of [Fullcalendar Vue](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-vue). I continually get  the following error when:

`Error: viewType "timeGridWeek" is not available. Please make sure you've loaded all neccessary plugins`

I have the required plugins installed:

```
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2"
"@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.1"
"@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1"
"@fullcalendar/vue": "^5.3.1"
```

And am importing them as prescribed in the [Demo App](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/blob/master/vue/src/DemoApp.vue), but I always get that error.

I believe this is due to something with my local project: I **am** able to get the demo app working fine on it's own, as well as copying the process on another project. It has never worked for this project.

**What can I try to do in order to resolve this?** I've deleted node modules, reinstalled all packages via npm, build the project for production, no luck. My full Vue component and `package.json` are below:

`Authenticated.vue`

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar, // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
  },

  data: function () {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [
          dayGridPlugin,
          timeGridPlugin,
          interactionPlugin, // needed for dateClick
        ],
        headerToolbar: {
          left: "prev,next today",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
        },
        initialView: "timeGridWeek",
        initialEvents: [], // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        weekends: true,
        select: this.handleDateSelect,
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick,
        eventsSet: this.handleEvents,
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
        eventAdd:
        eventChange:
        eventRemove:
        */
      },
      currentEvents: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleWeekendsToggle() {
      this.calendarOptions.weekends = !this.calendarOptions.weekends; // update a property
    },

    handleDateSelect(selectInfo) {
      let title = prompt("Please enter a new title for your event");
      let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

      calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

      if (title) {
        calendarApi.addEvent({
          id: createEventId(),
          title,
          start: selectInfo.startStr,
          end: selectInfo.endStr,
          allDay: selectInfo.allDay,
        });
      }
    },

    handleEventClick(clickInfo) {
      if (
        confirm(
          `Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`
        )
      ) {
        clickInfo.event.remove();
      }
    },

    handleEvents(events) {
      this.currentEvents = events;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "SPA-Starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --open",
    "s3": "vue-cli-service serve --open --port 3000",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.3.2",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.3.1",
    "@fullcalendar/vue": "^5.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "buefy": "^0.8.20",
    "bulma": "0.9.0",
    "date-fns": "^1.29.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.6.0",
    "primeflex": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "primeicons": "^4.0.0",
    "primevue": "^2.0.5",
    "v-tooltip": "^2.0.3",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-google-autocomplete": "^1.1.0",
    "vue-html-to-paper": "^1.3.1",
    "vue-js-modal": "^2.0.0-rc.3",
    "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.28",
    "vue2-leaflet": "^2.5.2",
    "vue2-timepicker": "^1.1.4",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.1.1",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0-0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.0.1",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17",
    "style-resources-loader": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by upgrading my Vue version from `2.5.17` to `2.6.11` after noticing the other projects that it worked on were using this version.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar, // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
  },

  data() {
    return {
      calendarOptions: {
        plugins: [
          dayGridPlugin,
          timeGridPlugin,
          interactionPlugin, // needed for dateClick
        ],
        headerToolbar: {
          left: "prev,next today",
          center: "title",
          right: "dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay",
        },
        initialView: "timeGridWeek",
        initialEvents: [], // alternatively, use the `events` setting to fetch from a feed
        editable: true,
        selectable: true,
        selectMirror: true,
        dayMaxEvents: true,
        weekends: true,
        select: this.handleDateSelect,
        eventClick: this.handleEventClick,
        eventsSet: this.handleEvents,
        /* you can update a remote database when these fire:
        eventAdd:
        eventChange:
        eventRemove:
        */
      },
      currentEvents: [],
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleWeekendsToggle() {
      this.calendarOptions.weekends = !this.calendarOptions.weekends; // update a property
    },

    handleDateSelect(selectInfo) {
      let title = prompt("Please enter a new title for your event");
      let calendarApi = selectInfo.view.calendar;

      calendarApi.unselect(); // clear date selection

      if (title) {
        calendarApi.addEvent({
          id: createEventId(),
          title,
          start: selectInfo.startStr,
          end: selectInfo.endStr,
          allDay: selectInfo.allDay,
        });
      }
    },

    handleEventClick(clickInfo) {
      if (
        confirm(
          `Are you sure you want to delete the event '${clickInfo.event.title}'`
        )
      ) {
        clickInfo.event.remove();
      }
    },

    handleEvents(events) {
      this.currentEvents = events;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: What did you change? I resolved my problem shortly after posting this - see answer below. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: changed from data: function() {} to data() {} => thats how it was showing in the documentation. Anyway glad you solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have forgotten to mention `registerPlugins` in module file

```
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import listPlugin from '@fullcalendar/list';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

FullCalendarModule.registerPlugins([ // register FullCalendar plugins
  dayGridPlugin,
  timeGridPlugin,
  listPlugin,
  interactionPlugin
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same bug and solved it by installing the **same version** of all fullcalendar packages.

In the case example above I see two versions (^5.3.2 and ^5.3.1), which may have resulted in incompatible plugins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).